# ASP.net listitem auto year range

Tags: asp.net, date, range, listitem

i have a registration form where a user fills in their date of birth.

Is it possible to have a piece of code that will auto update the list item each time there is a new year? Saves me having to go back to each form and add a new year eg 2014

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="date3" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="">#</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2010</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2009</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2008</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2007</asp:ListItem>
```

I already use this snippet to auto add a year for the copyright statement on the master page `<%=DateTime.Now.Year%>`

ANSWER

Code behind VB

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            AutoYearRange()

        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub AutoYearRange()
        date3.Items.Clear() '' This just ensures your list is now empty..
        For i As Integer = Now.AddYears(0).Year To Now.AddYears(-112).Year Step -1
            date3.Items.Add(New ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()))
        Next

        date3.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("- Please Select Date -", ""))

    End Sub
```

Thanks to Darren!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would populate this programatically.

So, in your code behind, do something like this - this is VB

```
    date3.Items.Clear() '' This just ensures your list is now empty..
    For i As Integer = Now.AddYears(-5).Year To Now.AddYears(10).Year
        date3.Items.Add(New ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()))
    Next
```

And in C#

```
   date3.Items.Clear(); // This just ensures your list is now empty..
   for (int i = Now.AddYears(-5).Year; i <= Now.AddYears(10).Year; i++) {
      date3.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
   }
```

This will take todays year, subtract 5 from it for your starting point and then go up to 10 years in the future. You can change the -5 and 10 to suit whatever you want.

If you wanted to add something like a blank one at the start, say something like "Select Date" you could add this in after running the loop above.

Do something like this (VB):

```
    date3.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("- Please Select Date -", ""))
```

Or C#

```
    date3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Please Select Date -", ""));
```

**Update**

To go in reverse you would simply start at the high number and go backwards, like this: (C#) - notice that we use `i--` instead of `i++` - this will subtract 1 on every loop rather than add one.

```
   date3.Items.Clear(); // This just ensures your list is now empty..
   for (int i = Now.AddYears(10).Year; i >= Now.AddYears(-5).Year; i--) {
      date3.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
   }
```

And in VB

```
    For i As Integer = Now.AddYears(10).Year To Now.AddYears(-5).Year Step -1
        date3.Items.Add(New ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()))
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks, my code behind coding isn't great still a lot to learn!, i've put this but it does not populate the list, do you know where i'm going wrong? `Sub AutoYearRange() date3.Items.Clear() '' This just ensures your list is now empty.. For i As Integer = Now.AddYears(-5).Year To Now.AddYears(10).Year date3.Items.Add(New ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString())) Next date3.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("- Please Select Date -", "")) End Sub`

Comment: Where are you calling `AutoYearRange()` ?

Comment: Think i'm getting it all wrong, i looked at this example on msdn `Sub Main()

        ' The assignment of m to n causes a compiler error when  
        ' Option Strict is on. 
        Dim m As Long = 987
        'Dim n As Integer = m 

        ' The For Each loop requires the same conversion, but 
        ' causes no errors. The output is 45 3 987. 
        For Each p As Integer In New Long() {45, 3, 987}
            Console.Write(p & " ")
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub`
And thought i was using the correct code

Comment: Call your `AutoYearRange()` inside the `Page_Load` method. and wrap it in an `if (!IsPostBack){ AutoYearRange(); }`

Comment: thank you! is it possible to add a sort to the code? It currently starts at 1901, would like it to sort descending instead

Comment: There you go - added a reverse along with explanation too.

Comment: Thanks but how does the VB code work? I swapped the values around and now i get an empty list box with 'Please select date'?